# Google Analytic Reporting and Google Tag Manager - Double Counting Visits

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have added GTM to my website with success and it is reporting all pertinent data to GA. However, when I review the source code for the page I see several deprecated GA tags that were used to measure UX, but are still on the page. Example:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Visitor Type', 'LOGGED IN', 2]);_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XXXXXXXX Login', 'START']);" onkeydown="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Visitor Type', 'LOGGED IN', 2]);_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XXXXXX Login', 'START'])
```

Does this send a pageview every time the event is fired? If so, are these added to my pageviews essentially double, triple counting pageviews because the event is firing. I have switched to UA and realize these are old GA event code.

Comment: Just to nitpick, _trackEvent, while it would affect your bounce rate, would never be recorded as a pageview (which would require a _trackPageView call).

Answer (score 2):

If you already have GTM tags that are sending data to GA, then you can remove any redundant code that you were using to track the same things, prior to implementing GTM. You will be sending in replicated data which will skew your reports. All tagging can get accomplished through GTM now. However, if you were using the older GA object (ie. _gaq) then it may not necessarily be a problem. The best thing to do is to remove it, at least for code cleanliness.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does thank you, but I am confused re: the older GA code, are you saying that if we are still using the old _gaq, but have switched to Universal in combination with GTM then it is a problem, but if I am using GTM with old GA, not Universal, then it is an issue. I am goijg to start removing all of them. I like clean code!

Comment: You want to avoid having concurrent instances of GA and UA code, regardless of whether you are using GTM or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have only partly [migrated to Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#migration).
The one thing [Nyuen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2391544/nyuen) didn't mention above is that GA and UA javascript events can only fire if their corresponding tracking code is still available on the page. If you have removed your tracking code and moved them into the GTM container, then **these events can create javascript errors**. They could actually be breaking functionality on your site. 
If the GTM container and GA / UA tracking code are both running on each page and you have configured event tracking in GTM, Analytics will receive duplicate data.

A [partial tag migration](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/google-tag-manager-video-and-q.html) is possible, but I have not seen an example one yet:
http://www.optimizesmart.com/google-tag-manager-implementation-guide/